# No pdf produced by simple document

Tags: pdf, texmaker

I just moved from Ubuntu to Mint. I installed TexMaker on the new system and now it won't produce a pdf for even a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

TexMaker does make the aux and log files and is not throwing any errors. Here is my log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2013.12.5) 6 DEC 2013 15:17
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**Test.tex
(./Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
No file Test.aux.
\openout1 = `Test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
(./Test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
197 strings out of 495031
2091 string characters out of 6181531
46622 words of memory out of 5000000
3494 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
23i,1n,17p,151b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Unlike any other time I've installed TexMaker on a linux distro, TexLive was downloaded automatically. This time I had to install it myself. I'm wondering if maybe there is some other package that I'm missing that is necessary for creating the pdf? Otherwise I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: There's nothing to produce in your minimal document, so there will be no output. What about `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}test\end{document}`?

Comment: ahh thanks... I'm pretty sure that in the past texmaker/texlive has generated empty pdfs for me so I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: @plattnum Try to compile `\documentclass{article}\listfiles\begin{document}test\end{document}` and then update your question with the contents of `.tex` file and `.log` file.

Answer (score 3):

At least TeX is smart... an empty document (no resulting content within the `document` environment) leads to no output pages, as mentioned in your `.log`:

```
No pages of output.
```

To see whether the installation or setup is fine, consider a less minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```